# required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable Error

Tags: scala, spray, reactivemongo

Hey im pretty new to Spray and reactive mongo .

Im trying to return a list of result as json but i'm having some issue  with converting the result  to list of json.

*this is my model*

```
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID
import reactivemongo.bson.Macros

case class Post(id: BSONObjectID, likes: Long, message: String, object_id: String, shares: Long)

object Post {
  implicit val reader: BSONDocumentReader[Post] = Macros.reader[Post]
}
```

*the Mongo method*

```
 def getAll(): Future[List[Post]] ={
 val query = BSONDocument(
  "likes" -> BSONDocument(
    "$gt" -> 27))
   collection.find(query).cursor[Post].collect[List]()
}
```

*and this is the route*

```
val route1 =
  path("posts") {
    val res: Future[List[Post]]= mongoService.getAll()
    onComplete(res) {
      case Success(value) => complete(value)
      case Failure(ex)    => complete(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

**error**

```
type mismatch; found : List[com.example.model.Post] required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
```

thanks,

miki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to define how a `Post` will be serialized, which you can do via a spray-json Protocol (see the [docs](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) for more detailed information). It's quite easy to do so, but before that, you'll also need to define a format for the `BSONObjectId` type, since there's no built-in support for that type in spray-json (alternatively, if `object_id` is a string representation of the `BSONObjectId`, think about removing the `id` property from your `Post` class or change it to be a String):

```
// necessary imports
import spray.json._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

implicit object BSONObjectIdProtocol extends RootJsonFormat[BSONObjectID] {
    override def write(obj: BSONObjectID): JsValue = JsString(obj.stringify)
    override def read(json: JsValue): BSONObjectID = json match {
      case JsString(id) => BSONObjectID.parse(id) match {
        case Success(validId) => validId
        case _ => deserializationError("Invalid BSON Object Id")
      }
      case _ => deserializationError("BSON Object Id expected")
    }
}
```

Now, we're able to define the actual protocol for the `Post` class:

```
object PostJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val format = jsonFormat5(Post.apply)
}
```

Furthermore, we'll also need to make sure that we have the defined format in scope:

```
import PostJsonProtocol._
```

Now, everything will compile as expected.

One more thing: have a look at the [docs about the DSL structure](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/#understanding-extractions) of spray. Your `mongoService.getAll()` isn't within a `complete` block, which might not reflect your intentions. This ain't an issue yet, but probably will be if your route get more complex. To fix this issue simply put the future into the `onComplete` call or make it lazy:

```
val route1 =
  path("posts") {
    onComplete(mongoService.getAll()) {
      case Success(value) => complete(value)
      case Failure(ex)    => complete(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Now i have an issue with the  search query...
 collection.find(query).cursor[Post].collect[List]()
could not find implicit value for parameter reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[com.example.model.Post]
not enough arguments for method cursor: (implicit reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[com.example.model.Post], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)reactivemongo.api.Cursor[com.example.model.Post]. Unspecified value parameters reader, ec.

Comment: I don't see any search query in your question, but have you made sure that your reader of the `Post` companion object in scope?

Comment: i added the mongo method im the main post, and also import  this 
import com.example.model.PostJsonProtocol

Comment: No, I meant that the reader for `BSONDocumentReader[Post]` doesn't seem to be available. It's hard to tell why this is the case without seeing your complete code, therefore I created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edgarmueller/8ed5f4c2ad6c63e44202) that contains the complete listing, that works for me. So, you might want to compare your version against mine to find the issue.

Comment: your code is working nice but when implement it inside a trait 
i can't import   import PostJsonProtocol._ 
trait MyService extends HttpService { 
 import PostJsonProtocol._ // wont compile 
}

Comment: added a [gist] with the code
 (https://gist.github.com/miko-code/6c520e9b22ab19de9542)

Comment: Move your `PostJsonProtocol` together with the implicit `BSONObjectIdProtocol `  outside the `MyService` actor, such that it is at top-level, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edgarmueller/14b426671c07fa6be6ae).