# what does this scala code do?

Tags: java, scala

I am still new to Scala.
I found this code inside Spray framework.

I am trying to understand what the method signature means:

```
 /**
 * Completes the request using the given arguments.
 */
def complete: (⇒ ToResponseMarshallable) ⇒ StandardRoute = marshallable ⇒ new StandardRoute {
  def apply(ctx: RequestContext): Unit = ctx.complete(marshallable)
}
```

What does the `=>` operator do here? I thought it was used for creating a closure?
What is the assignment to marshallable being done here? why is it done outside the brackets?

A java version of this code would be nice to see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does => and () => mean in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951895/what-does-and-mean-in-scala)

Comment: no. as i mentioned i get that => means creating a closure. but i dont understand in the context of the signature here

Comment: It also means other things, as explained in the second answer on that question.

Comment: (Though the general case may be sufficiently covered in that question, this is actually pretty tricky to parse, I think. I'll try to answer it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So.

The first thing to notice is that `complete` is declared with a `def`, so it is a method, but the parentheses that look like they might be method arguments come *after* the colon `:`.

So they are not in fact method arguments. `complete` is a no-argument method!

Then what's up with the parens after the colon?

`(⇒ ToResponseMarshallable) ⇒ StandardRoute` is the *return type* of the no-arg method complete. The function `complete` *returns a function* that accepts an expression of type `ToResponseMarshallable` and returns a `StandardRoute`.

OK. But then what's up with the arrow *before* `ToResponseMarshallable` in the function signature `(⇒ ToResponseMarshallable) ⇒ StandardRoute`?

In a function signature, an `⇒` prior to the type name signifies a "[call-by-name](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/functions_call_by_name.htm)" argument. Following java, Scala by default evaluates all expressions in an argument list, and then evaluates the method body, substituting the evaluated values for the variable. But Scala also supports call-by-name semantics, in which an *expression* is substituted unevaluated into a function, and re-executed every time that it is named. `complete` returns a function whose single argument has call-by-name semantics.

Following the equals sign is just the implementation of this method. The expression beginning with `marshallable ⇒` is an anonymous function, or function literal, or lambda (all names for basically the same thing). `marshallable ⇒ "hello"` would be a function that accepts (by name) a `ToResponseMarshallable` and returns the String "hello". But we need a method that accepts a `ToResponseMarshallable` (by name) and retuns a `StandardRoute`. So we have `marshallable ⇒`*<expression that evaluates to a StandardRoute>*

That *<expression that evaluates to a StandardRoute>* is just an anonymous inner class, an implementation of `StandardRoute` that overrides its `apply` method.

And we're done! We (hopefully) understand all the pieces, and what this declaration means.

Comment: you said, `complete` returns a function that accepts an expression of type StandardRoute, but doesn't the returned function *return* StandardRoute (instead of accepting it)?

Comment: argh! yes. let me fix that and pretend it didn't happen.

Comment: that's, um, what i meant to say.

Comment: it's a long time since i've looked at Spray with any care. but it looks like `ToResponseMarshallable ` is just a handle on a thing that can be marshalled into an HTTP response. If the thing passed to the function returned by `complete` were something ordinarily passed back, XML or JSON or a plaintext String, i'm guessing there would be implicit conversions to `ToResponseMarshallable `. if you want to pass back special things, you'd have to define conversions. but i'm only guessing! (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130260/required-spray-httpx-marshalling-toresponsemarshallable-error)